# Xamarin iOS EventStore.Getcalendars returning 0

Tags: ios, xamarin, calendar, ekeventstore

I am having an issue where either the reminder calendar or event calendar, depending on which displays the popup first, creates multiple calendars and does not save any of the events/reminders.  I have the properties set in the plist.  Below is the code I am using to request access for the events and reminders:

```
            var calendarEvent = await ANApi.FetchCalendarInfoAsync(AppCore.CurrentAppInfo.AppId);
            calendarEvent.Count();

            foreach (var calEvent in calendarEvent.ToList())
            {
                if (calEvent.Type == 1)
                {
                    AppEvent.Current.EventStore.RequestAccess(EKEntityType.Event, (bool granted, NSError err) =>
                        {
                            if (granted)
                            {
                                lock (_lock)
                                {
                                    CreateCalendar(EKEntityType.Event);
                                    CreateEvent(calEvent);
                                }
                            }

                        });
                }
                else
                {
                    AppEvent.Current.EventStore.RequestAccess(EKEntityType.Reminder, (bool remGranted, NSError remErr) =>
                    {
                        if (remGranted)
                        {
                            lock (_lock)
                            {
                                CreateCalendar(EKEntityType.Reminder);
                                CreateReminder(calEvent);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

The code works fine if I am only receiving events or reminders, but since I am receiving both events and reminders, it is failing to create my calendars properly.

This is how I am creating the calendars:

```
    public void CreateCalendar(EKEntityType type)
    {
        bool calExists = false;
        var appName = NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleDisplayName");

        //This returns 0 calendars, depending on which event's request was displayed first.  
        EKCalendar[] calendars = AppEvent.Current.EventStore.GetCalendars(type);
        foreach (EKCalendar cal in calendars)
        {
            if (type == EKEntityType.Event)
            {
                if (PersistentLayer.Instance.GetString(Constant.CALENDAR_ID) == null)
                    calExists = false;
                else if (cal.CalendarIdentifier == PersistentLayer.Instance.GetString(Constant.CALENDAR_ID))
                    calExists = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (PersistentLayer.Instance.GetString(Constant.REMINDER_CALENDAR_ID) == null)
                    calExists = false;
                else if (cal.CalendarIdentifier == PersistentLayer.Instance.GetString(Constant.REMINDER_CALENDAR_ID))
                    calExists = true;
            }
        }
        //Create a Calendar based on the App's name.  If name cannot be found use App Calendar
        if (!calExists)
        {
            EKCalendar calendar = EKCalendar.Create(type, AppEvent.Current.EventStore);

            if (appName != null)
                calendar.Title = appName.ToString();
            else
                calendar.Title = "App";
            EKSource localSource = null;

            foreach (EKSource source in AppEvent.Current.EventStore.Sources)
            {
                if (source.SourceType == EKSourceType.CalDav)
                {
                    localSource = source;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (localSource == null)
                return;

            calendar.Source = localSource;
            calendar.CGColor = new CGColor(255, 255, 0);
            NSError calError;

            AppEvent.Current.EventStore.SaveCalendar(calendar, true, out calError);
            if (calError != null)
            {
                this.SimpleAlert("Error saving Calender", calError.ToString(), "OK", null);
                return;
            }

            //Store the calendar Id so we can use it when saving events
            if (type == EKEntityType.Event)
                PersistentLayer.Instance.Edit().PutString(Constant.CALENDAR_ID, calendar.CalendarIdentifier);
            else
                PersistentLayer.Instance.Edit().PutString(Constant.REMINDER_CALENDAR_ID, calendar.CalendarIdentifier);
        }
    }
```

I believe that there is some sort of race condition going on, but I have not been able to figure it out.  I tried multiple things to try and get it to work, but I have not had any success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out.  First, I broke the code up and created all the reminders received followed by the events.

At first, this gave me a Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010 when trying to create the events.  The way I solved this was to reset the event store.  Once I did this, the Calendars created properly, for both reminders and events, and both events and reminders were added to their respective calendars.